# Iframe elements blocking reusable top menu

Tags: javascript, html

**Background**

So I have developed a top menu through basic HTML and CSS. This is saved as `Top_Menu.html` which works fine.

Top_Menu.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #EBE8E4;
  color: #222;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: #888;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 610px; 
}

  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;

      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s; 
    }

      nav > ul > li > a > .caret {
        border-top: 4px solid #aaa;
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;

        -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
          -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
        -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
          transition: color 0.1s linear; 
      }

      nav > ul > li > a {
        color: #aaa;
        display: block;
        line-height: 56px;
        padding: 0 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

        nav > ul > li:hover {
      background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
    }

    nav > ul > li:hover > a {
      color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    }

    nav > ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
      border-top-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    }

  nav > ul > li > div {
    background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }

    nav > ul > li:hover > div {
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
    }

      nav > ul > li > div ul > li {
        display: block;
      }

        nav > ul > li > div ul > li > a {
          color: #fff;
          display: block;
          padding: 12px 24px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

          nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a {
            background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1);
          }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="kitchendisplay.php">Calendar</a></li>
    <li>
  <a href="">Lists<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="kitchendisplay2.php">Grocery List</a></li>
                <li><a href="kitchendisplay3.php">Tasks</a></li>
                <li><a href="kitchendisplay4.php">Current Meals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="NAS.php">Media</a></li>
    <li>
  <a href="">Cooking<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="meat.php">Meat Temperatures</a></li>
                <li><a href="smoker.php">Smoker</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
        <li><a href="Hubitat.php">Hubitat</a></li>

</ul>
```

I am attempting to reuse this menu across multiple pages so I have put the following in my head:

```
<Head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</Head>
```

and then call up the top menu with the following:

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
      $("#nav-placeholder").load("Top_Menu.html");
});
</script>
<!--end of Navigation bar-->
```

The rest of the page is pretty straight forward. Directly below the menu I place an embedded google calendar with the following:

```
<iframe src="Link to google calendar" style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:5px;border-width:0" width="600" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

**Problem**

The problem is that my top menu's drop down is always behind my google calendar:

[image]

Loading just the menu, it is supposed to look like:

[image]

**What I have tried**

So I do know the elements can have their Z-index defined so I tried to define the google calendar to a high one (z-index:10):

```
<iframe src="Link to google calendar" style="position:absolute;z-index:10;top:80px;left:5px;border-width:0" width="600" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and placing my top menu to a low z-index (z-index:1):

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
      $("#nav-placeholder").load("Top_Menu.html");
      $("#nav-placeholder").style.zIndex = "1";
});
</script>
<!--end of Navigation bar-->
```

but unfortunately this does not help. Am I missing something for how to make my menu always be on top?

Comment: I would read up on z-index [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: @Tuneer Thanks for the help! Figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your menu z-index higher than iframe, try it and let me know

Comment: haha well that is a start I guess as I had my index backwards.. Still no fix yet but that is a big start indeed!

Answer (score 0):

`iamousseni` got me down the right track that the higher the Z-order, the more on top it will be. I was thinking of it backwards. The solution is that where I created my Top_Menu.html I have to assign the z-index to the elements as they appear (the drop down effect)

Within this section:

```
nav > ul > li > div {
    background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;

    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }
```

I put `z-index:100;` as in my case I will never exceed 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by setting the `z-index` of the dropdown menu within your `li` tag as

```
nav>ul>li>div {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/nv5preyw/